# How to obtain values of variables passed to ejs in a linked javascript file in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ejs

I am trying to build an electron app. An EJS file has variable values passed to it from the main process. I want to obtain these variables in the javascript file linked to renderer process. I tried the following :

```
<script>
    var details = <%= details %>
</script>
```

But I recieve an error `expression expected`.
How can I do this? I am new to electron and nodejs, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the generated source code.

If the value of `details` is, when you convert it to a string, anything other than valid JS syntax then this will error.

For example, if `details = "Hello, world"` then the generated HTML page will look like this:

```
<script>
    var details = Hello, world
</script>
```

which will treat `Hello` like a variable name and then error.

**You need to encode your data**

Since JSON was designed as a subset of JS literal syntax, you can encode it as then and then the client-side JS parser will convert it back to an object / string / whatever it was in the first place.

```
var details = <%- JSON.stringify(details) %>
```

Comment: details is of object type. `var details = <%= JSON.stringify(details) %>` This doesn't solve the issue, still throws the same error.

Comment: Missed that in my initial pass. You need to insert it without escaping for HTML as that will change the quotes and break the JS.

Comment: `var details = <%- JSON.stringify(details) %>` works. But I am confused, `console.log(typeof details)` shows that it is an object and `JSON.parse(details)` returns an error. Didn't we make the JS object (details) into a string ? Thanks for the input !

Comment: @SinadinShan — I explained why that is the case in the last paragraph of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Don't think you need to use any decorations since you are already in JS.

Try this:
`<script>console.log(details);</script>`

Comment: That won't work. The JS program written in EJS and generating the HTML document as output is a **different** program to the one that the browser reads from the `<script>` element. They don't share variables.